# Fundamental Questions: Building vs Compiling vs Rendering vs Coding vs Running?

Tags: rendering, build-process

I'm using [Urho3D](https://urho3d.github.io/) on Raspberry Pi, but the following questions apply to all platforms.

What should I do in order to reduce the load of online real-time rendering of the game? Does building/compiling/rendering the game (before running it) makes it easier and lighter to be run afterwards?

When making animations with 3dsmax, we use high-end computers to design the animation and render it. After that, any low-end and simple computer can play the animation. Now can we use a similar approach? Can I build/compile/render the game in a high-end machine and run the game in a low-end machine?

What is exactly the difference between building/compiling/rendering when designing a game, and running/real-time-rendering when playing the game?

Does a game needs rendering when after designing? Or all the renderings all left to the playing time!?

Comment: What do you call "rendering" the game?

Comment: @Kromster , I don't know!! Is there such thing!? Something that is done in the design process, so that real-time rendering of the game (while playing) gets easier and faster.

Comment: Some games use pre-rendered animated scenes (aka cutscenes). But this doesn't allow the required flexibility you need for gameplay.

Comment: It is hard to understand what you are really asking when you are trying to describe it in terms you don't really understand yourself. I would recommend that you either try to research the meaning of the terms you are using (feel free to ask on stackexchange if you can't find a good explanation) or try to describe your questions in terms you are more familiar with.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking about pre-processing or [space-time tradeoffs](https://simple.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-time_tradeoff). This is where we do some heavyweight work before play time, storing the results for fast lookup later or using them to optimize the game to minimise processing load during play. There's a huge range of tricks that fall into this category, including "baking" of lightmaps & visibility information, compressing/chunking assets for fast loading, etc. But these tend to be very specific to what you're doing. If you want help optimizing your game, tell us more about it.

Answer (score 2):

> What should I do in order to reduce the load of online real-time
>   rendering of the game? Does building/compiling/rendering the game
>   (before running it) makes it easier and lighter to be run afterwards?

Building/compiling are always required... or you would have no game to run!

> Does a game needs rendering when after designing? Or all the
>   renderings all left to the playing time!?

You've confused pre-rendering with rendering. *Pre*-rendering generates images which are rendered (i.e. drawn to screen) at runtime. You always have to render at runtime or the player will see nothing!

For a pre-rendered 2D game, here is the process:

- (Produce model assets) Designer builds models, texture, setup materials, rig, animate etc.
- (Produce image assets) Designer pre-renders (NOTE: not the same as "renders", see end of this list) models from all desired angles & positions, and under all desired lighting conditions, to images/textures, according to designer/developer specs.
- (Produce code) Developer writes all code required to load & display images. This can be done in software or hardware-accelerated mode. Also all other game code is written / updated.
- (Build) Developer builds code, which includes tasks like code linting, generating files and directories, *compilation*, formatting of Max assets, and many others.
- (Run) loads images/textures (via software or hardware-accelerated renderer, underlying mechanisms may vary). (startup)
- (Run) advances the simulation and and updates all positions / animation frames. (repeats)
- (Run) renders what player must see this frame. (repeats)

Once you've run the game, if you don't like what you see, then you typically go back to design and coding, rebuild the game, then try again.

Some games, like the original Starcraft, Command & Conquer, or Diablo, used pre-renderings for the reason you mention - they are cheap to display at runtime. All the calculations needed to arrive at those pixels has already been done. Essentially, it's cached data that you just load and display. OTOH, true 3D games without pre-rendering can display any object in any orientation / lighting etc. at any time - but it must calculate a lot of factors before it can do that, and that is costly / may be slow. HTH.